# Local variable problem in python, variable is not defines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project and keep getting variable not defined errors when I run the script. How can I solve this without declaring global variables

```
def func1():
    x = 1
def func2():
    y=5
    x + y = z
    print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

`x` is in the local scope of `func1`, thus it can not be read from `func2`. You can use `global x = 1` but I would not recommend it. Instead pass `x` to `func2`:

```
def func1():
    x = 1
    return x
def func2(x):
    y = 5
    z = x + y # You had this backwards as well (i.e. x + y = z)
    print(z)
x = func1()
func2(x)
```

Comment: You'll also need to change `x + y = z` to `z = x + y`.

Comment: Didn't even notice thank you.